AWS Glue - Boto3 - ImportError - cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (/tmp/openai_libs.zip/urllib3/util/ssl_.py)
I am building an ETL in AWS Glue 4.0. I created a custom transforms that read config file (json) from s3 and based on config, do some processing. Here's the example code:
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from awsglue import DynamicFrame
import json
import boto3

def impute_static_values(self, bucket, key):
  
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    file_content = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    config_data = json.loads(file_content)
    df = self.toDF()
    for column,value in config_data['static_values'].items():
        df = df.withColumn(column, lit(value))

    # Convert back to DynamicFrame
    transformed_dynf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, self.glue_ctx, self.name)

    return transformed_dynf

# Add this method to DynamicFrame class
DynamicFrame.impute_static_values = impute_static_values

Error Message: ImportError - cannot import name 'DEFAULT_CIPHERS' from 'urllib3.util.ssl_' (/tmp/openai_libs.zip/urllib3/util/ssl_.py) 
Some solutions suggested to use python 3.10 but it can not be controlled on Glue (Visual ETL). Any recommendations are recommended.

Did you figure it out?
